# getting error as list index out of range while connecting to sharepoint using python

Tags: python, file, sharepoint, upload, shareplum

i am getting error in below code as list index out of range

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
authcookie = Office365('http://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/', username='XXXXXXXXXX', password='*********').GetCookies()
site = Site('http://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/Trial',  version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/General')
folder.upload_file('Hello', 'new.txt')
```

error-

```
data = envelope[0][0][0]
    File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1161, in lxml.etree._Element.__getitem__
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and actually i dont have  file - "src\lxml\etree.pyx